Isobaric expansion vs Isobaric Free Expansion
Our teacher while teaching thermodynamics talked about free expansion, isothermal free expansion and adiabatic free expansion.
But for isobaric free expansion, he said that's not possible (it's not a thing) because when the pressure is a constant, volume of gas can't be increased.
But doesn't isobaric expansion mean just that, the volume of gas increasing without pressure changes.
So, is isobaric free expansion a thing? Yes/No? Why?

A free expansion implies no external pressure holding back the expansion.

If the volume of gas increases, but pressure stays the same, then something must be steadily supplying heat.
PV = nRT  yields T = PV/nR
If P stays the same, and V increases, so must T.
This is obviously not a system in equilibrium.
A simple example would be a flask with a rubber stopper and glass tube, in which one inserts a drop of water half-way down the tube. The pressure in the flask equals current atmospheric pressure, ignoring the minuscule weight of the droplet. Warm the flask in your hand and the drop ascends: temperature increased, volume increased, pressure unchanged (still balances atmospheric).
